# Easiest way to get birthday info of all friends through graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for the least resource intensive way of getting all friends' birthday information by a given user object Id. Probably using Event Object since birthdays of friends are visible inside events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done something similar in the following way:

1) Like Awais pointed out - you need to first get the extended permission from the user at the time of login to access their birthday information

`<fb:login-button perm="user_birthday, friends_birthday"></fb:login-button>`

2) There are different ways of doing this, but if you are not using php sdk, you can get the friends birthday as follows

```
all_friends_profile = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+uid,name,birthday_date+from+user+where+uid+in+(select+uid2+from+friend+where+uid1%3Dme())&format=json&access_token=...'));

foreach($all_friends_profile as $profile)
{
   echo $profile->name.' birthay='.$profile->birthday_date;                  
}
```

Just replace the access token in the above code and it should loop through all your friends and print their birthdays

3) Basically the query I have used is

```
select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

quite easy.Just take extended permission of user birthday then just query user table to get birtday

```
<fb:login-button perm="user_birthday, friends_birthday"></fb:login-button>
$user=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='.$cookie['access_token']));
foreach($user[data] as $friend)
{
    $fql    =   "select name, birthday_date from user where uid=".$friend['id'];
    $param  =   array(
                'method'    => 'fql.query',
                'query'     => $fql,
                'callback'  => ''
            );
            $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);


    print_r($fqlResult);
```

Hope it will work

Comment: is there any another way using like Event object instead of fql ?

Comment: yes you can just traverse your $user[data] array. Take print_r($user). you will see the brithday is there. You can simply access that using loop