# How to sort result from Facebook birthday API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I use this to get the list of friends by birthday:

`$frnd = $facebook ->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday&access_token='.$access_token);`

How do I sort the result and still keep it under the same structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array based on a specific field in the array?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2382326/how-to-sort-an-array-based-on-a-specific-field-in-the-array)

Comment: Not sure quite what you're asking here. Are you asking how to sort a json array in php? If so, the link provided is probably useful.
Or are you asking the most efficient way (least data returned) to get the birthdays of all of the friends you can? For the latter, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548673/get-age-of-friend-on-facebook-with-ruby-via-rfacebook/5556774#5556774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments - this helped me in going for the right direction and this is the answer:

```
        $frnd = $facebook ->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday&access_token='.$access_token);

        $arr = $frnd["data"];
        function so ($a, $b) {
            $a_dt = explode("/",$a['birthday']); // dt[0] is month, dt[1] is day
            $b_dt = explode("/",$b['birthday']); // dt[0] is month, dt[1] is day

            $a_dt_time = mktime(0,0,0,$a_dt[0],$a_dt[1], date("y"));
            $b_dt_time = mktime(0,0,0,$b_dt[0],$b_dt[1], date("y"));

            return ($a_dt_time < $b_dt_time) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        uasort($arr, 'so');

        $frnd["data"] = $arr;
        // debug: print_r($arr);
```